# C++ header guards won't compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

Can't get any code using header guards to compile in vs 2010. For example:

```
#ifndef SIMPLE.H
#define SIMPLE.H

#include <iostream>

class Place {
private:
int m_xplace;
int m_yplace;
Place(){}
public:
Place(int x, int y) : m_xplace(x), m_yplace(y) {}
void Move(int x, int y);
void set_place(int x, int y) {m_xplace = x, m_yplace = y;}
int get_place_x() {return m_xplace;}
int get_place_y() {return m_yplace;}
};
#endif
```

I get this output from compiler:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: 1, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>e:\projects\1\1\simple.h(1): warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor     directive - expected a newline
1>e:\projects\1\1\simple.h(2): error C2008: '.' : unexpected in macro definition
1>e:\projects\1\1\simple.h(1): warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline
1>e:\projects\1\1\simple.h(2): error C2008: '.' : unexpected in macro definition
========== 
Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Am i missing something obvious here? I'm quite sure i have the syntax correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use `.` in the identifier.

Try this instead:

```
#ifndef SIMPLE_H
#define SIMPLE_H
```

Comment: Now that i look back on it, the output is quite clear as to what is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it happens. I overlook things a lot too, and start looking for the error in the wrong places (like the code itself).